# Remove a bit of a string before a word

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have string like this:

```
G:\Projects\TestApp\TestWeb\Files\Upload\file.jpg
```

How can I remove all text before "Files" (G:\Projects\TestApp\TestWeb)?
The string before files can changed, so I can't count characters and remove them after 20 characters.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Do you mean that the path prior to \files varies?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

try this

```
string s = oldString.Substring(oldString.IndexOf("Files"));
```

Thanks for Meta-Knight's comment,

if another "Files" can be in early part of the string then better would be..

```
string s = oldString.Substring(oldString.LastIndexOf("Files"));
```

Comment: This is certainly valid, but I would like to add that you want to find a unique part of the string you want to keep (g:\uploadfiles\john\Files\Upload\ would fail).  You could consider .jpg or \Files\Upload\ as well.  Also, suggest .tolower() so you aren't impacted by case differences.

Comment: I would use LastIndexOf instead. It would minimize the risk of errors.

Comment: @Frozzare, be careful with this, in that  if there can be another "Files" in the beginning somewhere, you may want to reverse the code as my edited answer shows.

Comment: In addition to using LastIndexOf, it's also a good idea to search for "\Files\" instead of just "Files" in case you have a path like "c:\My really important Files\Pictures\Files\Adult Files\NSFW" for instance.